# SSRS IE 9 page footer rendering issue

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have one report and there is some data in the report. The problem is when the report is shown in the reportviewer, the page footer overlaps on the body part. It is fine while printing but the problem is while viewing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to upgrade your Report Viewer control. [According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960138.aspx) only version 2012 started to support IE9.